# Typescript specify general type but keep specific keys and values

Tags: typescript, types, key, operators, literals

Sometimes is really useful to use `as const` at the end of an object declaration, that way you create a literal singleton type, the downside is that you cannot specify a type without losing the specific keys like the example bellow

[image]

Would be nice to keep the literal key static values while type checking

Is there a way to keep the keys as specific literals, but check for the required general type?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already available in Typescript 4.9 with the [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator)

By using it instead of the type, the specific type is preserved and the general is used for type checking only

[image]